# Lag difference by group in R

Tags: r

Is there way to perform 2 operation for each group. Example shown below

```
> asd <- data.frame(Cat = c("A","B","B","A","B","A"), Start_num = c(2, 5, 1, 6, 6, 4), End_num = c(3, 7, 4, 7, 8, 5))
> asd
  Cat Start_num End_num
1   A         2       3
2   B         5       7
3   B         1       4
4   A         6       7
5   B         6       8
6   A         4       5
```

Expected output

```
Cat Start_num   End_num   True/False
A       2        3        TRUE
A       4        5        TRUE
A       6        7        NA
B       1        4        TRUE
B       5        7        FALSE
B       6        8        NA
```

So basically ,
First we need to sort the dataframe by Start_num in ascending order by group **Cat**
Second, we need to create another column **True/False** that tells if the Start_num of 2nd Row is greater than End_num of 1st Row. Example First row is True since for **A** (4 - 3) is True and so on. But the last record of each Cat should NA since it ends there. Is it possible to acheive? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next. You can arrange initially, and then use `lead()` to make the comparison and reach the expected output:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- asd %>% arrange(Cat,Start_num) %>%
  group_by(Cat) %>%
  mutate(Var=lead(Start_num)>End_num)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Cat [2]
  Cat   Start_num End_num Var  
  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>
1 A             2       3 TRUE 
2 A             4       5 TRUE 
3 A             6       7 NA   
4 B             1       4 TRUE 
5 B             5       7 FALSE
6 B             6       8 NA
```